# How to disable app labels in KDE taskbar

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, antergos

I think I checked all the options, but I cannot find the one that turns off labels of running apps on the taskbar in Antergos KDE. They look like this:
[image: Antergos desktop]

I know it can be done, because it looks just the way I want in Manjaro KDE:
[image]

Does anybody know how to disable those labels?

Answer (score 10):

Right click on taskbar > Alternatives > Icons only task manager

Comment: For the help in finding answer I thank Yoshi2889 from #antergos IRC channel.